# Strange glitch with NIS

Tags: centos, nfs, automount, nis, yp

Good day. One of the network users with the NIS account (yp and automount) has some problems: after editing network service configufation file (/etc/sysconfig/network) and rebooting (/etc/init.d/network restart) - the client machine was hung and as a result was rebooted by power button, after that user when trying to log into any machine in the network see this picture with hanging gnome interface, no reaction, no icons:

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/880x495q90/546/ejdc.jpg

Other users of the network haven't experienced any problems with nis, services nis and nfs were rebooted.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Switch to a text console / boot a text console or ssh in to the system and look at the logs.

Comment: I've already taken a look to the configuration files, they are clear (without suspicious lines).

Comment: configuration fils are not log files. Look in /var/log/* for any relevant information. Right now there is nothing in your question that is at all useful.

Comment: I've found several relevant erros in .xsession-errors file in the auto.fs home folder of the account which expirienced this problem:
gnome-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporary unavailable) on X server :0
*** (gnome-panel:2779): WARNING**: panel-applet-frame.c:1288: failed to load applet 0AFIID:GnoteApplet:
System exception: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0